# How to force a WPF binding to refresh in F#

Tags: wpf, f#

I have a binding that points to a view model and later on I update the view model with a new one , how can I update the binding also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found it , in case it helps somebody else :

```
this.RaisePropertyChanged("Property")
```

replace property with your member property.